# Passing Index Path through Navigation Controller - Update CoreData Record

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a diary app, and have a table view with a list of entries. A add new button to add a new record, and clicking on the row in the table lets you edit the record. Both Add new and Edit take you to a different view controller which is all set up in a Navigation controller.

I have got most of it working, except I am having issues updating the record. When editing it adds a new record not updates the old one (Using the current entries data). Before moving to another vc I had it working with a dialog box.

Having a look at the code it looks like it is because I am not passing through the Index path. Does anyone have any ideas how I do this? My current code is below. Any questions please let me know.

**Adding New Record**

```
@IBAction func addNew(_ sender: Any) {
        let newEntry = DiaryEntry(context: self.context)
        newEntry.entry = self.entryEntry.text //The Main Entry
        newEntry.date = Date() //The Date (Auto)
        newEntry.rating = Int16(self.ratingInt) //The Rating
        newEntry.entryName = self.entryName.text //The Entry Name
        
        do{
            try self.context.save()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            //print("Saved correctly")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
        self.fetchData()
    }
```

**Updating Current Record**

```
@IBAction func updateRecord(_ sender: Any) {
        let newEntry = DiaryEntry(context: self.context)
        newEntry.entry = self.entryEntry.text //The Main Entry
        newEntry.date = Date() //The Date (Auto)
        newEntry.rating = Int16(self.ratingInt) //The Rating
        newEntry.entryName = self.entryName.text //The Entry Name
        do{
            try self.context.save()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            //print("Saved correctly")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
        self.fetchData()
    }
```

As far as I understand, I believe the issue lies in the newEntry context part. However I am a bit lost.

This is what the code was when I had it in a Alert box (And it worked)

```
let entry = self.items![indexPath.row]
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Entry", message: "Edit an entry to your Diary", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField()
    let textfield = alert.textFields![0]
    textfield.text = entry.entry
    let saveBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { (action) in
        entry.entry = textfield.text
        do {
            try self.context.save()
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
        self.fetchData()
    }

    let cancelBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(saveBtn)
    alert.addAction(cancelBtn)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I know it is something simple, but I can't work it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing the edition VC you could save the indexPath.row of the item to be edited and the in updateRecord you put the code you had before instead of the newRecord code.

Comment: When you say "save the indexPath.row", do you mean store it in a variable? or save it to core data?

Comment: In a instance variable in your navigation controller